# The limit of a strongly convergent sequence of linear bounded operators from a Banach space to a normed space

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, proof-explanation, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be a Banach space and $Y$ be a normed space.
If the sequence $\{T_n\}$ of bounded linear operators from $X$ into $Y$ is strongly convergent. Then there exists a bounded linear bounded operator $T:x \rightarrow Y$ st

$lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} T_n(x)=T(x)$ $\forall x \in X$

The Proof.

[image]

I don't understand how the author deduced that $T$ is bounded.
why did he write $\|Tx-T_nx\| \leq \|T-T_n\| \|x\| <\epsilon$
all that we so far know about the operator $(T-T_n)$ is that it is a linear operator, it is not bounded so we can write this inequality $\|Tx-T_nx\| \leq \|T-T_n\| \|x\| <\epsilon$ furthermore he writes $\|T-T_n\| \|x\| <\epsilon$ but the assumption said $T_n \rightarrow $T$ strongly not uniformly.
I'm confused about this part

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm confused, what notion of strong convergence is the author using?  Usually we say a sequence of bounded operators converges strongly if it converges to a bounded operator in the strong operator topology. By this meaning, the claim is a tatology.

Comment: Yes he defines strong convergence as you said. Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces, and $T_n : X → Y$ and
$T : X → Y$ are bounded linear operators. We say that: $T_n$ converges strongly to $T$  if
$T_nx → T x$ for all $x ∈ X$

Comment: So the statement of the theorem is absurd.

Comment: I believe the theorem and proof (minus the errors already point out) work if you change "$\{T_n\}$ is strongly convergent" to "For each $x\in X$, $\{T_nx\}$ is convergent in $Y$".  Then it's a standard exercise in a first functional analysis class.

Comment: Regardless, if these aren't lecture notes for a class you're currently taking, I'd recommend switching to some other reference material. If these are lecture notes, I'd recommend supplementing them with some other standard references.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct; this is a small (but fixable error).

At that point in the proof, you cannot conclude that $$\|T-T_n\|<\epsilon$$ for $n$ large enough.  But you can hold $x$ fixed, and then conclude that $$\|Tx-T_nx\|<\epsilon$$ because $T_nx\to Tx$.  The following sequence of inequalities then shows that $$\|Tx\|\leq\|T_nx\|+\epsilon\|x\|$$  Thus $$\frac{\|Tx\|}{\|x\|}\leq\sup_n{\|T_n\|}+\epsilon$$ which is independent of $x$.  The boundedness of $T$ then follows.

Answer (score 0):

Me too I don't understand, you cannot want to show that an operator is bounded and in the argument, use the fact that it is bounded. Another argument: $T(x)=lim_nT_n(x)$ implies that $\|T(x)\|=lim_n\|T_n(x)\|\leq \|T_n\|\|x\|\leq k\|x\|$. The $k$ is the $k$ you have defined by using the uniform boundedness principle.

Comment: Your argument is flawed; the claim that "$\lim_n\|T_nx\|\leq\|T_k\|\|x\|$ for some $k$" is not true in general.